# Mac OS Mojave Terminal: Save history per tab

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, macos-mojave

I've found a few older posts on this but none of the solutions seem to work. I have terminal configured to open a Window Group on startup. This group has 2 windows with a few tabs each. When I exit terminal and restart, the histories for each tab are all merged into one history that is shared across all of the tabs. I'm trying to get it so that each tab retains its own history upon restart. In case there is a conflict, here are my .bash_profile and .bashrc

#### .bashrc

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

#### .bash_profile

```
if [ -f /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
fi

source /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh

green=$(tput setaf 2)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
bold=$(tput bold)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
PS1='\u:\w\[$blue\]$(__git_ps1)\[$reset\] \$ '
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"

export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```